# Thunar - deleted both ends after copy

Tags: xubuntu, samba, thunar

Using Thunar 1.6.15 and copying large multi-gigabyte files from my main Xubuntu system to a Windows 10 share.

After the copy attempt, not only did the copy fail, but it appears to have deleted the file on both ends. The file I was trying to copy is gone and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I did a simple drag-n-drop in Thunar so I think it used the gvfs SMB support.

It's inconvenient but not the end of the world. I can recover the data but it'll take a little time.

In the past, it seems like I could copy large amounts of data if I did it one at a time. But if I drag over multiple large files, I run into trouble.

Any ideas on what went on here?

Comment: I suspect you 'moved' the file instead of your intended 'copy'.  (default is move)

Comment: I suggest that you use `rsync` for such operations. It is very reliable and has many options. The default is 'copy', it will not delete anything on the source side (unless you specify that explicitly). You can check that the transfer was correct with `md5sum` (compare the checksum at both ends). If there are still problems, I think it is not because of Thunar or `rsync`, but some low level service, that is responsible for the data transfer or write process.

Comment: I dragged and dropped between the source window and the target window. Sounds like the default is move. If the it is, then if the move failed, it deleted the source?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid that is what happened.

Comment: Well wait a minute. I just tested dragging from my Documents folder to a temp directory in the share.
It made a copy.
Not sure if it did a move.

Comment: @NRaygun, You can search for the file with `sudo find / -iname "*pattern*"` where pattern is a fragment of the name, that you can remember (It could be the whole name too).